# Unavailable resources in Nunit, ignore result

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing

I'm doing integration testing for my code (with Nunit) and I wonder whether it's possible to dynamically set the result of a test to ignored when some external resource like a web service is unavailable (503 or network down). I don't want neither to successfully pass the test nor fail the test.

If setting it to ignore in runtime is not possible, what would be the best practice to handling unavailability of resources in integration testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Assert.Ignore()`.  Calling that will immediately end the test with an "ignored" result.  See documentation [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.6).